# Userfriendly CMS for a large organisation

Tags: looking-for-a-script, cms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am looking for a CMS for a large organization.

There are many sites managed by many webmasters. The size of the sites range from pretty small to pretty large (60,000+ pages).

The choice of technology does not matter, as long as the product meets the following requirements:

- Allows complex workflows to accomodate the multiple needs of a lot of clients. (Many levels of revision, translation, approval, etc.)
- Very easy for the users (Very easy for developpers too is great but could live without)
- Has content history (It is possible to view what the content on a page was at a specific date)
- Must be multilingual (At least French and English)
- Has a flexible security model
- Has good performance
- The layout of the pages must be highly configurable (not sure if I should write as all CMS probably meet this criteria)
- It must be possible to publish content that respects the WCAG 2.0 AA standard

Can you point me in the direction of a CMS that meets all those criterias ?

Comment: Also, urls of translation must be predictable(Let's say one page has the url: mydomain.com/topic-eng, the french version of topic  should be topic-fra). The requirement is not strict about eng, fra per se, but it should be easy for a user to guess what the url for an other language is.

Answer (score 1):

I've made good experiences with the [Django-CMS](https://www.django-cms.org/). Here are some points off the top of my head:

- Most of our non-tech-savvy clients manage the content of their site
  themselves, so I think you could consider it user-friendly.
- It's definitely easy to use for developers (and it uses Django :) ).
- I know that you can see the change history of a page, but I'm not sure if you can see what the content looked like at a specific time. If not, there might be a plugin for this.
- It is multilingual.
- Good security model.
- Performance is good I guess.
- Pages can easily be customized. You can write custom plugins for specific elements.
- Lots of plugins exist. We use the news plugin a lot for example.
- You can use [rosetta](https://github.com/mbi/django-rosetta) for translations.
- The language of the page is visible in the URL (eng/intro and fr/intro for example)

Comment: Does it support complex workflows ?

Comment: I think it does, you can give users different levels of access for example. I've never used it this way tough, so you might have to try it out yourselves.

Comment: Workflows are not just about security accesses, it is also about the chain of approval/revision before content gets online. It has to be flexible because depending on the branch, the approvals required to publish are not always the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your developers are familiar with java/jsp I'd recommend **Liferay Portal** ([here's an introduction from the documentation](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/portal-architectu-5)).

It's open source, built for large organizations, has a clear user-role setup.

Comment: Do you have experience using it? From what I can tell, a lot of CMS look great on paper, but when you actually try to use them, they tend to be overly complex and not userfriendly at all.

Comment: I have some experience using it, I've started building my own themes and I'm working with some devs who are building portlets. It's wonderfully customisable, however somewhat complex. But I love how well it integrates with Eclipse (IDE).

Answer (score 0):

My company uses [Ektron](http://www.ektron.com/) Which is very powerful, stable and offers the features you listed.

Comment: It looks like an interesting product, I might take a look at it.